# What happens if during an SQLite transaction in android, a second thread attempts a transaction on the same table?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, transactions

I do not really understand the proper usage pattern of SQLite transactions in Android.

Lets say method A starts a transaction. During the execution of the transaction another method B will attempt to do a transaction on the same table (possibly on the same row).

What will happen?

Will the method B "wait" until method A has finished the transaction, and then execute the transaction?
Or will the transction of method B fail?

How do I properly handle that?

To be more precise:

- Method A should query (inside a transaction) if a certain row already exists, and if so, return the row, if that certain row does not exist yet, it should in insert that row, and return the newly inserted row.
- Method B should query (inside a transaction) if a certain row already exists, update that row, if the row does not exist yet, Method B should insert that row.

The idea is to make sure, that, no matter which method first executes, to have either have inserted or updated that particular row
I am not even sure, if these can be achieved on the level of SQLite transactions, or do I have to synchronise methods in Java?

If so, can any body post an example, how such a synchronisation has to be coded in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'A' modifies a table in transaction, 'B' should be blocked (inside SQLite itself) until 'A' is committed.  It's pretty similar to java synchronization except it's dealing with persistent data.  Some of details depend on isolation levels

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "transaction".

If you mean transactions established by SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction or beginTransactionNonExclusive, then the rules for those methods apply. I would say that you should do beginTransaction for Method A, run it until finish, and then finish the transaction. If Method B attempts to do a transaction, it should encounter an Exception. Transactions allow you to do multiple operations and back them all out if they don't work.

I can't tell if separate threads will work or not, from the little you've posted. You might want to consider using an IntentService to handle your transactions; that way, one transaction can't start until the previous one ends.

Answer (score 0):

The transactions are established by "beginTransaction", so from what I understand, the transactions are exclusive.

@sseand: Interestingly, the german version of mentioned wikipedia aricles is somewhat different from the english version. The german version states, that an application with isolation level of "serializable" must be able to handle serialization errors, and re-run the respective transaction. So I would expect, that there is a "SQLiteSerializationException" for that. But I cannot see such an exception in the API. So, does the SQLite API for Android automatically handle that?